# Access denied when trying to add Windows User account

Tags: c#-4.0, userprincipal

I am trying to programmatically add a user like this below but get an access denied message on the Save. I'm running locally on Windows 7 and the code resides in a console app.

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="userName"></param>
/// <param name="password"></param>
/// <param name="description"></param>
public static void CreateUser(string userName, string password, string description)
{
    PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, null);
    System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal u = new UserPrincipal(pc);
    u.SetPassword(password);
    u.Name = userName;
    u.Description = description;
    u.UserCannotChangePassword = true;
    u.PasswordNeverExpires = true;
    u.Save();

    GroupPrincipal gp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, "Users");
    gp.Members.Add(u);
    gp.Save();
}
```

Any ideas? I tried supplying an administrators username and password and still get the same error.

The console app gets executed like this:

```
 ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    startInfo.UserName = userName;
                    startInfo.Password = securePassword;
                    startInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
                    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    startInfo.FileName = batchPath;
                    startInfo.Arguments = operationLogID.ToString();
                    Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Here is a rough view of how the code is set up:

- Console App test harness gets executed in debug mode.
- I check for a user and if they don't exist..then I try and create it shown above. This is where the error occurs.

Comment: Are you running the whole app in administrator mode?

Comment: where did you supply admin username and password? The u.SetPassword and u.Name is the password and name of the user you're creating, but has nothing to do with the application having rights to create a new user.

Comment: It still seems likely that you're not running as administrator.  Have you tried running your app from a command-line as administrator?  (If you are unsure how to do that, this may help: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/run-a-command-as-administrator-from-the-windows-vista-run-box/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you're logged in as admin, you need to run your console as admin.  Here's how to launch a console as admin: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/run-a-command-as-administrator-from-the-windows-vista-run-box/.

Then find your console app and run it.

Good luck!

-Michael